# Looking for an application for the start-up phase of romance writing

Tags: software-recommendation, tools

Apologice in advance for the maybe off topic question.

Is there any Ubuntu application that helps for the start-up phase of story writing?

I'm looking for such a tool that provides me the capability to build up the story diagrams, define characters, project the evolution of a saga the saga.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/30267/is-there-an-alternative-for-scrivener-a-tool-for-writers-to-arrange-ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [celtx](http://celtx.com/index.html).

Comment: Looks promising and it has also multilanguages support. OK it not ubuntu native you have to install by yourself and setup about:config variables but I testing it...

Answer (score 3):

https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9/is-there-a-special-software-for-writers

Comment: thanks for the link I had no idea of a community for writers :-)

Comment: very welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

What I advise you first is to try to install yWriter with Wine. Works perfectly. Celtx is a bit more awkward. Although, look at PyRoom, which is a useful thing.

Comment: Good yWriter it has also a Linux version so no need for wine :-)

Comment: Bad that it works crappy, depending on your Mono version. Sometimes PE app in wine works better, than the native version, especially if the author is not a Linux guy.